# How to add languages to github projects

Tags: github, version-control

[Github image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXpUF.png)

Hi, how can I add more languages to the description of my github repository ? I hope the image above explains what I mean,
cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The language is defined by GitHub itself based on language files you have in your source code. let say you have `.js` files in your source code then it will show javascript.

Answer (score 0):

GitHub uses the open source [Linguist](https://github.com/github/linguist) library to determine file languages. The displayed language is simply the most used language in your project.